# Run python script as a process with specific name

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a script with a telegram bot, which I can start in the background in "always listening" mode. But when I'm opening the Activity Monitor on Mac I can see a new process with a specific PID but with "Python" name only.

Is it possible to declare a specific name for this (or any) process?

I want to create a script that will be able to kill and restart specific processes by a command.

Comment: You can use **pyinstaller** to turn your script into a macOS executable. https://www.pyinstaller.org/

Comment: just use PID number(write to somewhere) and run your app on shell (not idle).

Answer (score 0):

Seems there is no way to set a unique process name on mac but it's possible to get unique ID of the running process. You can use such way:

```
import os
unique_pid = os.getpid()
print(unique_pid)
```